# Is inline keyword valid in Kotlin class constuctors?

Tags: kotlin, constructor, class-constructors

Suppose you have 2 Kotlin classes

```
class Battery(
    val carbon: Any,
    val zinc: Any
)
```

```
class RemoteControl(
    /* inline */ val battery: Battery,
    val buttons: Any
)
```

Notice the commented out `inline` keyword in `RemoteControl`. Uncommenting it doesn't produce an error in Intellij.

Is this valid Kotlin code and what does it do?

My expectations is that it is equivalent to

```
class RemoteControl(
    val carbon: Any,
    val zinc: Any,
    val buttons: Any
)
```

But it doesn't appear to do anything.

I'm using Kotlin 1.3.72 and Android Studio 4.0.1

Comment: Remember that a Kotlin property consists of accessor method(s), and a backing field (if needed).  So if the `inline` is valid, then it probably applies to the getter method (and setter, if mutable).  But if you want to be sure, why not compile it, and look at the bytecode?

Comment: Never though of doing that. I tried to find any difference in bytecode with different types, high ordered functions and delegation but haven't come up with with a scenario where there'd be difference. Maybe it's just a compiler error that allows putting that keyword there or there's just one niche use case where it works?

Comment: `val battery: Battery = TODO()` ?  lol

Comment: I think it makes the getter and/or setter inline. You can mark the getter or setter specifically as well. Very limited usefulness since you don't pass lambdas to getters and setters.

Answer (score 2):

The `inline` modifier can be used on the property (on the property of primary constructor as well):

```
// var property
inline var battery: Battery
    get() = Battery("carbon", "zinc")
    set(v) {  }

// val property
inline val battery: Battery
    get() = Battery("carbon", "zinc")

// primary constructor
class RemoteControl(inline  val battery: Battery)
```

In such a case, all accessors are marked inline automatically. At the call site the accessors are [inlined as normal functions](http://At%20the%20call%20site%20the%20accessors%20are%20inlined%20as%20normal%20functions.).

Applying inline to a property that has a **backing field**, or its accessor, results in a **compile-time error**:

```
// error: "Inline property cannot have backing field"
inline var battery: Battery
    get() = Battery("carbon", "zinc")
    set(v) { field = v } // we use backing field here
```

There is more [info](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/inline-properties.md).

Comment: Inlining primary constructor parameter with a backing field contradicts your second statement. It also makes no sense since you cannot customize accessor methods there anyway. At least on JVM it produces identical bytecode as non-inline one.

Comment: You labeled your second example as “immutable” but it is certainly not immutable because it returns a new instance each time it’s called.